# Best/easiest way to embed an HTTP site within an HTTPS site?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, iframe, https

I have spun up a Shiny Server on an Amazon EC2 instance. The webpage pointing to this app is an unsecured HTTP site ([see here](http://ec2-3-134-88-235.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3838/allappfolders/app1/)).

I also have a Wordpress site that has an SSL security certificate. I'd like to embed my app in this Wordpress site using something like an iframe. It is my understanding, that an iframe pointing towards an unsecured HTTP will not work on a secured HTTPS page.

I tried adding an HTTPS security rule to the EC2 server, but it is limited to the 443 port and my Shiny Server is on the 3838 port. Does anyone have a good solution for how to solve this issue?

[My network security rules.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRK8u.png)

Comment: What are the outbound rules? You also need a corresponding entry in outbound to respond to the request.

Comment: Ah, I see. Right now I only have two outbound as such: https://imgur.com/a/0u2MJpu